# como puedo continuar mi codigo

Tags: array, c

estaba desarrollando este programa con arrays, lo primero que necesito es saber si el valor del primer array es par, si es par se debe guardar en otro array aparte y decir, desde que posicion partio y en cual temino por ej: 2 partio en pos. 0 y termino en 0, pero el 8 partio en pos. 2 y termino en pos. 1. lo que no logro es que indique bien donde empezo y donde termino..

```
#include <stdio.h>

   int main(void) {
    int vectorA[7] = {2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 20, 12};
    int vectorB[7];
    int i;
    int aux;

  for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    if (vectorA[i] % 2 == 0) {
      aux = vectorA[i];
      vectorB[i] = aux;
      printf("\neste es vectorB: %d", vectorB[i]);
    }
  }
  printf("\n2 posicion or. %d, posicion actual %d");
  printf("\n8 posicion or. 2, posicion actual 1");
  printf("\n4 posicion or. 4, posicion actual 2");
  printf("\n20 posicion or. 5, posicion actual 3");
  printf("\n12 posicion or. 6, posicion actual 4");
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Estás leyendo el elemento de la posición `i` de `vectorA` y guardando en la posición `i` de `vectorB`. Entonces el elemento parte de la posición `i` de `vectorA` y termina en la posición `i` de `vectorB`.

Answer (score 2):

Por favor, nota que si tienes un array con 7 elementos, al ser el primer índice 0, el último será necesariamente el 6. No puedes iterar de 0 a 7 porque entonces accederás a una octava posición del array que no es tal. Estarás accediendo a memoria que no pertenece al array.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
//            ~~ <<--- MAL
```

En cuanto a tu problema, puedes guardar en una variable la posición del reemplazo anterior.

Si necesitas guardar esta información en un vector, entonces lo mejor es crear una estructura para almacenar los dos valores:

```
typedef struct
{
    int inicio;
    int fin;
} DATA;

DATA vectorB[7];

int anterior = 0;
int indiceB = 0;
for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
{
    if (vectorA[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        vectorB[indiceB].inicio = anterior;
        vectorB[indiceB].fin = i;
        anterior = i;
        indiceB++;
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<indiceB; i++)
{
    printf("%d - partio: %d, termino %d\n", vectorA[vectorB.fin], vectorB.inicio, vectorB.fin);
}
```